# vb.net formclosing with dialog

Tags: vb.net

I can not believe I am asking this question after reading similar questions mostly OLD and here is the frustration I had code that worked just as desired then I changed to Option Strict ON now more issues than I bargained for

Here is the code that works OR I should say worked at one time
In fact it still works on another test project?
The Handles Me.Closing has a RED ERROR squiggle line under it

```
    Private Sub frmTwo_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing

    Const message As String = "YES Exit Program" + vbCrLf + vbNewLine + "NO Back to Form Start"
    Const caption As String = "Exit OR Cancel"

    Dim result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Application.Exit()
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        frmStart.Show()
        Me.Hide()
        'tbMessage.Text = "CANCEL"
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Tested this code on two forms frmStart and frmTwo on frmTwo it does not stop Debugging

```
    Private Sub frmStart_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    If MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        e.Cancel = False
    Else
        Me.Hide()
        frmTwo.Show()
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I turned Option Strict OFF so it is not the ISSUE

Comment: Me.Close is a method, not a property.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=netframework-4.8

Why aren't their parameters for FormClosing?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.closing?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Pete-S- Happy to add parameters if I knew what and where to add My real concern is the CODE at the top first posted works as it is now in another project only error is e.Cancel = True need to be commented out

Comment: Can you change the 2019 method: Private Sub frmStart_FormClosing() Handles Me.Closing to Private Sub frmStart_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs Handles Me.Closing?  I've seen it where VS doesn't add the parameters when using the "fix".

Comment: @Pete-S- Change to Private NO LUCK BC36663 Visual Basic Option Strict On does not allow narrowing in implicit type conversions between method and delegate.

Comment: @Pete-S- I added this but now the Dialog is defunct  Delegate Sub CancelEventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems with Option Strict ON VB.Net does not like constructing the Sub this way

```
Private Sub frmStart_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
```

And as mentioned you then need to include `Imports System.ComponentModel`

So to STOP playing e.Cancel = True and e.Cancel = False just write a Sub as seen below and Call that Sub from some Button no need for `Imports System.ComponentModel`

```
Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    CloseForm()
End Sub
Public Sub CloseForm()
    Const message As String = "YES Exit Program" + vbCrLf + vbNewLine + "NO Return to Form Start"
    Const caption As String = "Exit OR Return"

    Dim result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

    If result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        Application.Exit()
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        Close()
        frmStart.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Recreating the closing event, the event parameters are `(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs)` not the different types.  I'm testing this against .Net Framework 4.8, what .Net are you targeting?

This worked as expected:

```
 Private Sub frmStart_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing
        Const message As String = "YES Exit Program" + vbCrLf + vbNewLine + "NO CANCEL"
        Const caption As String = "Exit OR Cancel"

        Dim result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        If result = DialogResult.No Then
            Me.Text = "CANCEL"
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: @Pete_S_ I have this setting <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" /> Also noticed my SQLite package not declared I downloade System.Data.SQLite.Core How do I change the framework to 4.8 ? W7 64 bit? With VS 2019 Version 16.6.4

Comment: 4.7.2 shouldn't be an issue. Missing a package, that can cause cascading issues.  Have you tried changing the parameters to sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs

Comment: How to change the targeting framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Pete_S_ YES I removed ByVal tested both ways If 4.7.2 is OK lets not add another confusing variable My DB Read and Write work fine What Version of VS are you running I upgraded twice last week ? ? ?  This is my VERSION NUMBER Version 16.6.4

Comment: I have both 2017, 2019.  I tested the code in 2019.

Comment: If you haven't already tried.  Try recreating the frmStart_Closing event?

Comment: @Pete_S_ Here is what was missing Imports System.ComponentModel I am too use to auto Import of Dependencies I have no idea why it is not a feature in VS even my VB 6 would Auto Import Android Studio as well and NetBeans now and then

Comment: @Vector, glad you got it resolved!  I've been a fan of using NUGET to keep all the references up-to-date.

Comment: @Vector FYI `ByVal` is the default; by long experience with VBA, I always use it explicitly when typing code, but there is no functional difference between `ByVal` and nothing.